# How to get probability of new data point from probability object (fitdist)?

Tags: matlab, probability, distribution

I have fitted several probability distribution to my dataset by using the Matlab [`fitdist`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) function in the following way:

```
pd = fitdist(myDataset,distname)
```

From this function I got a probability distribution object `pd`. I now that I can calculate `mean(pd)`, `std(pd)`, `median(pd)` etc.

But how can I calculate the probability of a new data point according to the fitted distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the probability value thanks to the `pdf()` function.
First of all you can create your probability distribution object thanks to the `fitdist()` function, as you already did actually.

```
pd = fitdist(myDataset,distname);
```

Now, to gather the probability value for a point `myPoint` you can use `pdf()` as follows:

```
myProb=pdf(pd,myPoint);
```

where `pd` is the output from `fitdist()` and `myPoint` can either be a single point or a vector of points. Consequently, `myProb` will be a single point or a vector or points (respectively) since each value in `myProb` corresponds to a value in `myPoint`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Does the pdf function always return probabilities between 0 and 1 or do I have to made some consistency checks?

Comment: By definition, the area under the probability density function curve is 1 (such integral becomes a sum if we're using discrete values). It is actually impossible to have values greater than 1 or smaller than 0. If you want a more concrete proof, create your `pd` and then create `myPoint` as an array which spans loads of values (e.g. ±100) and then see `myProb` which values contains. You can as well plot `myPoints` vs `myProb` in order to see the shape of your `pd`

Comment: I have made some experiments. The pdf can be greater one because it is the pdf and not the probability. Should I use cdf instead if I'm interested in the probability? Edit: I have found the following explanation: "The integral of the pdf from -infinity to +infinity must be one. This does not put a limit on the "peak" of the pdf."

Comment: Keep in mind that the CDF will evaluate the probability that your variable *X* will take a value less than or equal to a given value *x*. You can as well evaluate the probability that *X* will take a value greater than or equal to *x* by doing `1-CDF`.

Comment: Now, I'm a bit confused. I have tried it with a naive bayes classifier. PDF worked while CDF did not work. The problem is that PDF can give values greater than one and is not the real probability. CDF does also not give the probability. So how can I compute the probability at the end of the day?

Comment: Again. The CDF gives you the probability that your random variable *X* will take a values less than of equal to a given value *x*. So it *does* return a probability value. If you want the probability of (let's say) `x=3`, well...you can't, since probability density functions are continuous functions. The probability value is the integral of your pdf and if the extremes are equal you'll always get 0 as result. As in the cdf case, you need to provide a range of values in order to perform your integral

Comment: You can as well approximate the integral with the Riemann sum. Let's see the following example: `pd = makedist('Normal','mu',0,'sigma',1/4); x=[-10:0.1:10]; y=pdf(pd,x); plot(x,y);  ss=sum(0.1*y); cc=cdf(pd,0);`. I've created a normal distribution with sigma=1/4 (peak is higher than 1). The `sum` command evaluates the integral all over the range and it returns 1 (Riemann sum, to be precise). The `cdf` command returns 1/2 because it integrates between `0` and (ideally) `+inf` and since the distribution has zero mean, we evaluate half of the bell curve...that's why it returns 1/2.