# How to calculate probability of a point using a probability distribution object?

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-density

I'm building up on my preivous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923750/how-to-get-probability-of-new-data-point-from-probability-object-fitdist) because there is a further issue.

I have fitted in Matlab a normal distribution to my data vector: `PD = fitdist(data,'normal')`. Now I have a new data point coming in (e.g. x = 0.5) and I would like to calculate its probability.

Using `cdf(PD,x)` will not work because it gives the probability that the point is smaller or equal to x (but not exactly x). Using `pdf(PD,x)` gives just the densitiy but not the probability and so it can be greater than one.

How can I calculate the probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a random variable `X` that follows the normal distribution with mean `mu` and standard deviation `s`.

Let F be the cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution with mean `mu` and standard deviation `s`. The probability the random variable`X` falls between `a` and `b`, that is P(a < X <= b) = F(b) - F(a).

In Matlab code:

```
P_a_b = normcdf(b, mu, s) - normcdf(a, mu, s);
```

Note: observe that the probability X is *exactly* equal to 0.5 (or any specific value) is zero! A range of outcomes will have positive probability, but an insufficient sum of individual outcomes will have probability zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what I initially wanted is P(X = a), that means a = b which will give F(b) - F(a) = F(a) - F(a) = 0

Comment: @machinery yes, that is correct. And that's why no one ever asks for P(X=a) for the normal distribution or most other continuous distributions (with the possible exception of during tests or on homework questions, to test understanding). P(X=a) = 0 for any random variable X with a continuous probability density function.

Comment: Ok but in a (gaussian) naive bayes classifier you fit a normal distribution for each feature and then you have to calculate P(X=a) for a new data point coming in... Can I just use the pdf value in such a case? Of course pdf can get bigger than one but higher pdf value means higher probability (density).

Comment: @machinery If you're trying to compare what is more or less likely, you probably want to use the pdf.

It would really be worthwhile to spend a few days to self study or get tutored on the basics of continuous probability so you're *really* secure on this stuff... it'll save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: So let's say I'm using the pdf to judge if an observation is more or less likely. Furthermore, I'm evaluating several values, i.e. probA = pdf(PD,x1), probB = pdf(PD,x2), ProbC = pdf(PD,x3). x1, x2 and x3 are data points. Now I would like to take probA * probB * probC to get the overall likelihood but because this can get very small I would like to take the negative log likelihood which is -(log(probA) + log(probB) + log(probC)). Is this valid, i.e. does this make sense?

Answer (score 4):

If the distribution is continuous then the probability of any point `x` is 0, almost by definition of continuous distribution. If the distribution is discrete and, furthermore, the support of the distribution is a subset of the set of integers, then for any integer x its probability is

```
cdf(PD,x) - cdf(PD,x-1)
```

More generally, for any random variable X which takes on integer values, the probability mass function `f(x)` and the cumulative distribution `F(x)` are related by

```
f(x) = F(x) - F(x-1)
```

The right hand side can be interpreted as a discrete derivative, so this is a direct analog of the fact that in the continuous case the pdf is the derivative of the cdf.

I'm not sure if matlab has a more direct way to get at the probability mass function in your situation than going through the cdf like that.

In the continuous case, your question doesn't make a lot of sense since, as I said above, the probability is 0. Non-zero probability in this case is something that attaches to intervals rather than individual points. You still might want to ask for the probability of getting a value *near* `x` -- but then you have to decide on what you mean by "near". For example, if `x` is an integer then you might want to know the probability of getting a value that rounds to x. That would be:

```
cdf(PD, x + 0.5) - cdf(PD, x - 0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probability theory is not my strength. ;) The distribution is continuous in my case (normal distribution). What does RHS and PMF mean? I think your explanation is for discrete distributions but how can I adapt it for continuous distributions?

Comment: @machinery You really should read up on how to calculate the probability of various outcomes using a probability density function and/or a cumulative distribution function.

With a discrete distribution, you sum up the probability of the various smaller, component events to get the probability of a larger event. (eg. the probability a die roll X is 3 or less is the probability P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3).) For a continuous distribution, the analogue to summing a probability mass function is integrating a probability density function. Integration is basically summation.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Integrating a probability densitiy function is exactly what the pdf function of Matlab does I think but this can become larger than one which is no more a real probability.

Comment: @machinery what you just wrote is not correct. The pdf function evaluates the probability density function of several well known distributions at the values passed into the function. To calculate a probability, that probability density function must be integrated or the cumulative distribution function must be used (which is the pdf integrated from -infinity to a specified value).

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks for the explanation. I'm still confused. How can I integrate the probability density function in Matlab? If I use the cumulative distribution function (cdf) then I would get the probability that X is smaller or equal to a certain value which is not what I want.